# decorating in two classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, decorator, attributeerror

I am not good with decorators in python, but I am trying to learn it.
I have two classes and I want to decorate one method in class "greeting" with  a method "_f" in class "decorate". the code is like this:

```
class greeting:
    def __init__(self,word):
        self.word=word
    @f._f
    def hi(self):
        print('hi')
    def bye(self):
        print('bye')

class f(object):
    def _f(foo):
        def display_wrapper (self):
            print('it is a decorator')
            self._g(self)
            foo(self)
        return display_wrapper
    def _g(self):
        print('a method in decorator')

word='hiiii'
obj=greeting(word)
print(obj.hi())
```

but an error occurs like this:
it is a decorator
AttributeError: 'greeting' object has no attribute '_g'.

if anybody knows what the problem is please tell me

Comment: One of the problems is that there is no instance of `f` to call `_g()` on.

Comment: The instance of `f` is `obj.hi`, not `obj` (which is what `greeting.hi` receives as its `self` argument).

Comment: the `f._f` calls of instance of `f._g`. But `greetings` doesn't have a function of `._g`

Comment: thank you so much. could you please modify my code? because i dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version works for some definition of works.

```py
class f(object):
    def _f(foo):
        def display_wrapper (self):
            print('it is a decorator')
            f._g()
            foo(self)
        return display_wrapper
    @classmethod
    def _g(cls):
        print('a method in decorator')

class greeting:
    def __init__(self,word):
        self.word=word
    @f._f
    def hi(self):
        print('hi')
    def bye(self):
        print('bye')



word='hiiii'
obj=greeting(word)
print(obj.hi())
```

Output:

```
it is a decorator
a method in decorator
hi
None
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it